# Global way to prevent empty string in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

Is there a global, database-wide way to prevent the insertion of an empty string into any varchar field in Postgres?

Even better, is there a system-wide way to silently convert all such empty strings into NULLs upon insert or update?

I think I could add a check constraint to every column definition: `CHECK (mycol <> '')`, but this is really tedious and error-prone. To do the silent conversion I'd probably have to write a bunch of triggers.

I will likely add some application-level rules to the insert and update routines to prevent empty fields, but that's even more tedious and error prone.

There's got to be a better way. Allowing empty strings in this app makes writing queries a lot harder.

Comment: In theory you could create a [domain](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createdomain.html) but then you would need to t specify the max length as a check constraint on those columns.

Comment: Are you striving for Oracle compatibility? That won't work, think of string concatenation.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe No, not looking for Oracle compatibility. Just trying to avoid junk in my database without doing too much work.

Comment: I see. I wouldn't see an empty string as junk. A NULL value means "unknown", while an empty string means "nothing". But it is up to you to determine the semantics of your data.